# запрос sql удалить повторяющиеся значения в колонке таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Друзья привет. Есть таблица(INT,INT,BIT):

| resourceId | userId | isBool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 15 | 1 |
| 36 | 15 | 0 |
| 25 | 16 | 1 |
| 47 | 84 | 0 |
| 47 | 84 | 1 |

В таблице в колонке resourseId могут встречаться повторяющиеся значения. Мне необходимо написать sql запрос, чтобы в колонке resourseId остались только неповторяющиеся значения(удалить дубликаты) а в оставшейся строке заменить userID на другое значение, допустим на 69.
Я знаю как изменить значение userId, через UPDATE и SET. Но я не могу сообразить как удалить дубликаты из resourceId.
Т.Е. после редактирования таблица должна стать такой:

| resourceId | userId | isBool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 69 | 1 |
| 36 | 69 | 0 |
| 47 | 69 | 0 |

Я вроде нашел подход через создание временной таблицы, копирование туда данных исходной таблицы с нужным условием, потом удаление исходной таблицы и копирование туда временной, не знаю, насколько это правильно, но реализовал оттуда только кусок с копированием во временную таблицу. (копирование туда работает неправильно, у меня копируются сначала resourceId а остальные колонки имеют значение null, потом userId а остальные колонки null, потом isBool, а остальные колонки null.) вот мой код

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempTable
CREATE TABLE #tempTable(resourceId INT,userId INT, isBool BIT); 
INSERT INTO #tempTable(resourceId) 
SELECT DISTINCT OriginalTableResourceId FROM ResourceBook 
INSERT INTO #tempTable(userId) 
SELECT OriginalTableUserId FROM ResourceBook 
INSERT INTO #tempTable(isBool) 
SELECT OriginalIsBool FROM ResourceBook

SELECT * FROM #tempTable
```

Comment: 36 у вас без дублей было, там тоже надо заменить на 69 ?

Comment: ага, userId изменяется во всей колонке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Оно использует обновляемый CTE.

Нет необходимости создавать и использовать временную таблицу.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и пример заполнения данных, начaло
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (resourceId  INT, userId INT, isBool BIT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (resourceId, userId, isBool) VALUES
(25, 15, 1),
(36, 15, 0),
(25, 16, 1),
(47, 84, 0),
(47, 84, 1);
-- DDL и пример заполнения данных, конец

-- начaло
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

-- найти и удалить дубликаты для resourceId
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY resourceId ORDER BY resourceId)
    FROM @tbl
)
DELETE FROM rs
WHERE seq > 1;

UPDATE @tbl
SET userId = 69;

-- тестирование
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: Спасибо, друг. То что надо!